# While remote debugging how are the pdb located (VS 2008)

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, remote-debugging

When the debugger is attached to a process on remote server -

What locations are searched for the pdb?
In what order?
(e.g. is it searched on the remote server (debuggee) or on the local client (debugger))

When I use the debugger to manually load pdb file from specific location - is the debugger looking for the file locally or is it the remote debugger monitor looking for the file on the?

Is there any article that describes that process?

Comment: What's the etiquette on fixing typos? Normally, I try to ignore them, not wanting to be a grammar troll or whatever, but in this question, they are mostly in a key term, which may keep this question from being found in searches, and thereby reduce its usefulness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The machine the debugger is running on loads the symbols (not the remote).

This article explains the basics of setting up where VS looks for symbols:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x54fht41(VS.90).aspx?ppud=4

This one explains how to set up a symbol server in the search path (which is particularly useful for Windows symbols):

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ttk8zy(VS.90).aspx

There are a lot of pitfalls for remote debugging (mainly having to do with connectivity and permissions/authentication).  See the following page for a list of links that you'll want to read up for details:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa(VS.90).aspx

Comment: As per the firs tlink you provided, it is actually the remote where the PDB files should be located on. (i.e. not the debugger machine)

Answer (score 0):

Is there any article that describes that process?

As you know, when the debugger starts a session, it begins to search for the location where the appropriate PDB are located. The [following article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37883/Symbols-File-Locator) describes the mechanism and the search order of the process.